# Continuity of a multivariable function assigned to a single value

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to use the definition of limit to show that the constant function $f(x,y) = 1$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^{2}$.  I.e. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)}$ $f(x,y)$ = $1$ for (a,b) $\in$ $\Bbb R^{2}$.

As the name implies this is hopefully simpler than it seems at the moment.
I know that the definition of the limit of function f(x,y) as it approaches (a,b) is:
$\lim_{ (x,y)\to (a,b)}f(x,y) = L$ and for every $\varepsilon$ $\gt$ $0$ there is a corresponding number $\delta$ $\gt$ $0$ that if (x,y) $\in$ D and $0$ $\lt$ $\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2}$ $\lt$ $\delta$ then $\vert{f(x,y) - L\vert}$ $\lt$ $\varepsilon$. To prove this would I say that $\vert f(x,y) - 1 \vert \lt \varepsilon$ whenever $0 \lt \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \lt \delta$?

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hopefully that is more legible!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your question is exactly.

Yes, the definition of continuity is that, $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y) = f(a,b)$$

Or stated in words, "for every $\epsilon>0$, find a $\delta>0$, such that whenever $|(x,y)-(a,b)|<\delta$ then $|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|<\epsilon$". For a constant function, any $\delta>0$ works automatically. I suppose your getting lost in writing a proof from the definition? The phrase "find a $\delta>0$" is the part you have to do. That is the part that requires a proof; show me that a $\delta$ can always be found. Give me a formula for finding such a $\delta$. Typically, $\delta$ will be a formula involving $\epsilon$; but in the case of a constant the difference in range-values is always zero, so any $\delta$ works. Here is a formal proof:

---

Proof. Let $\epsilon>0$ be an arbitrary number. I will choose $\delta=1$ which is positive, and show that this $\delta$ satisfies the definition of continuity. So, lets pick an $(x,y)$ such that $|(x,y)-(a,b)|<\delta=1$ ($(x,y)$ is now fixed). We now need to show $|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|<\epsilon$. But this follows immediately, since $f(x,y)=1$ and $f(a,b)=1$ (by definition because $f$ is a constant), so $$|f(x,y)-f(a,b)| = |1 - 1| = 0 < \epsilon$$

---

We have shown that no matter the $\epsilon>0$, we can always find a $\delta>0$ such that if $(x,y)$ is within $\delta$ of $(a,b)$, then $f(x,y)$ will be within $\epsilon$ of $f(a,b)$. Since $(a,b)$ was arbitrary, we have shown that $f$ is continuous at every $(a,b)$.